# categorical x data on bar charts python ggplot

Tags: python, bar-chart, data-visualization, python-ggplot

The picture illustrates the problem - can you get rid of these extra 'foo' and 'bar' ticks on the x-axis?

[image: Problematic x-axis]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_(ggplot2)/

Most importantly, the working code specifies stat='identity'.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"x" : ["foo", "bar"], "y": [2000,1500]})
plot = ggplot(aes(x="x",y="y"), data=df) +\ # y NOT weight
         geom_bar(stat='identity') +\ # stat='bin' by default
print plot
```